# How to use ProgressMonitorInputStream

Tags: java, swing, inputstream, progressmonitor

I know I must be missing something very obvious, but whenever I try to use the ProgressMonitorInputStream when copying a file, I never get the ProgressDialog popup.

The examples I see don't seem to do much other than wrap their input stream within the ProgressMonitorInputStream.

The docs say:

> This creates a progress monitor to monitor the progress of reading the input stream. If it's taking a while, a ProgressDialog will be popped up to inform the user. If the user hits the Cancel button an InterruptedIOException will be thrown on the next read. All the right cleanup is done when the stream is closed.

Here is an extremely simple example I put together that never pops up the dialog with a large file even if I `setMillisToPopup()` to an insanely small number.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class ProgressBarDemo extends JFrame {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private JButton button;

   ProgressBarDemo() 
   {
      button = new JButton("Click me!");
      ButtonActionListener bal = new ButtonActionListener();
      button.addActionListener(bal);

      this.getContentPane().add(button);
   }

   private class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener 
   {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Worker worker = new Worker();
         worker.execute();
         button.setEnabled(false);
      }
   }

   public void go() {

      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.pack();
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

   private class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
   {

      private void copyFile() {

         File file = new File("/Users/mypath/Desktop/WirelessDiagnostics.tar.gz");

         BufferedInputStream bis;
         BufferedOutputStream baos;
         try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
                  ProgressBarDemo.this,
                  "Reading... " + file.getAbsolutePath(),
                  bis);

            pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToPopup(10);
            baos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/mypath/Desktop/NewWirelessDiagnostics.tar.gz"));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int nRead = 0;

            while((nRead = pmis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               baos.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
            }

            pmis.close();
            baos.flush();
            baos.close();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         copyFile();
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void done() {
         button.setEnabled(true);
      }
   }
}

public class TestProj {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ProgressBarDemo demo = new ProgressBarDemo();
      demo.go();
   }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `copyFile` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this means the EDT is unable to respond to new events or paint requests until after the method returns.

Try placing the call within it's own `Thread` context...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(
    public void run() {
        copyFile();
    }
));
t.start();
```

Equally, you could use a `SwingWorker`, it's a little bit of overkill, but you get the benefit of the `PropertyChangeListener` or it's `done` method, which could be used to re-enable the `JButton`, should you want to prevent people from clicking the button while a copy operation is in progress

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

**Updated with example**

Copying a 371mb file, across the local disk...

[image: Copy]

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class ProgressBarDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JButton button;

    ProgressBarDemo() {
        button = new JButton("Click me!");
        ButtonActionListener bal = new ButtonActionListener();
        button.addActionListener(bal);

        this.getContentPane().add(button);
    }

    public void go() {

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void copyFile() {

        File file = new File("...");

        BufferedInputStream bis;
        BufferedOutputStream baos;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
                            this,
                            "Reading... " + file.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bis);

            pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToPopup(10);
            baos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("..."));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int nRead = 0;

            while ((nRead = pmis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
            }

            pmis.close();
            baos.flush();
            baos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            button.setEnabled(false);
            SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    copyFile();
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }

            };

            worker.execute();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProgressBarDemo demo = new ProgressBarDemo();
        demo.go();
    }
}
```

Remember, there is overhead involved in setting up the window and displaying, which needs to be factored in.  The system may "want" to display a window, but by the time the system has set it up and is prepared to display it, the steam may have finished copying...

**Extended Example**

*nb: I don't really like the `ProgressMonitor` API as I've not been able to find where the UI is synchronised with the EDT, this can cause issues in Java 7 & 8*

You could formalise the idea into a self contained worker, for example...

```
public class CopyWorker extends SwingWorker {

    private File source;
    private File dest;
    private Component parent;

    private ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis;

    public CopyWorker(Component parent, File source, File dest) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.source = source;
        this.dest = dest;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(source)) {
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
                pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
                        parent,
                        "Copying...",
                        is);

                pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToPopup(10);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int nRead = 0;

                while ((nRead = pmis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            pmis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

This attempts to contain the functionality, but also deals with the cleanup of the `ProgressMonitorInputStream` within the `done` method, making sure that it's done within the EDT.  I'd personally attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to it and monitor the `done` property to determine when the worker has completed and examine the return result in order to pick up any exceptions, this gives you the ability to handle the exceptions in your own way and de-couples the worker from your process

Comment: In an effort to write up a quick question I neglected to add in my example the fact that I'm using a SwingWorker class to do the copyFile. So that isn't a problem in my actual code.  I still never get the popup.  Thanks for that advice though!

Comment: Well, provide an example which does use `SwingWorker` so we can actually see what you're doing...

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Comment: This is exactly the approach I am trying at the moment. It's buggy - about 50% of the time, the application hangs inside the `close()` call. The reason behind this is that `ProgressMonitorInputStream#close` calls `dispose()`, and like all other AWT/Swing methods, this should not be called on a background thread. `close()`, then, cannot be called on the background thread and must be called on the EDT. I would actually suggest making a clone of `ProgressMonitorInputStream` which calls `invokeLater` when doing this, which is going to be my approach for working around this.

Comment: @Trejkaz Personally, I'd avoid using ProgressMonitorInputStream as I can't see where it's even synchronising  any of its functionality. You could also call close in the done method of the SwingWorker, but this couples the work to the copy process which I generally don't like doing either

Comment: @Trejkaz Normally, I would do the copying in the doInBackrgound method and use the SwingWorkers ProperyChangeListener support to provide progress notification to a custom UI.

Comment: I could do that too, but I decided to try `ProgressMonitorInputStream` because I would have had to implement the whole `FilterInputStream` myself still. Another reason I was trying this out is that our own custom GUI also has random hanging issues related to timing of dialog popups, and I figured maybe Swing itself would get it right... but I guess not.

Comment: @Trejkaz You could work around it by managing the streams outside the context of the Worker (or as part of the worker), so, as I said, you could use the `done` method or `done` property to close them, but that comes down to your needs...

Comment: @Trejkaz I added a self contained example, see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your program works on files, but when it comes to server and client streams, it 
    fails.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class FileReceive extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedInputStream bufferInput;
    private FileOutputStream fout;
    private BufferedOutputStream bufferOutput;
    private Socket client;
    private JButton button;
    private File fileinfo;
    ProgressMonitorInputStream pois;

    FileReceive() {
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        receiveFile();
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new FileReceive();
    }

    public void receiveFile() {
        try {
            fileinfo=new File(filepath);
            client=new Socket("localhost",9090);
            fout=new FileOutputStream(fileinfo);
            bufferOutput=new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            bufferInput=new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            pois=new ProgressMonitorInputStream(this, "reading", bufferInput);
            int ch;
            byte[] b=new byte[2048];
            System.out.println("Receiving File");

            while(-1!=(ch=pois.read(b))) {
                bufferOutput.write(b,0,ch);
            }

            pois.close();
            bufferInput.close();
            bufferOutput.close();
            fout.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```