# ProcessMonitorInputStream not showing dialog if you use process.getInputStream()

Tags: java, swing, process

I am trying to provide feedback to the user on a process that is started using a process. I am trying to do it using a `ProcessMonitorInputStream` but the input stream from the process is not working when used with the `ProcessMonitorInputStream` constructor.

```
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

        // Run scp command in windows with -etc meaning correct options
        processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "scp stacy@myhost.com:/home/stacy/archive/image*.jpg /home/stacy/downloads");

        try {
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            new Thread(() -> {
                ProgressMonitorInputStream pMonitorInputStream;
                try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                        pMonitorInputStream = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
                                null,
                                "Reading process stream",
                                // Problem is here?
                                process.getInputStream()))) {
                    ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = pMonitorInputStream.getProgressMonitor();

                    progressMonitor.setMaximum(fileSize);
                    progressMonitor.setMillisToDecideToPopup(100);
                    progressMonitor.setMillisToPopup(100);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    while ((bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
                        progressMonitor.setNote(bis.available() / 1000 + " more kb to read.");
                        //simulating some processing delay
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).start();
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If I change out `process.getInputStream()` for a typical `new FileInputStream(fileName)` then the swing dialog appears and displays the progress.

How do I get the progress monitor to show with process?

Edit:
Doing some debugging `bis.read(buffer)` is always returning -1 indicating the end of the stream but the process is not finished yet. The file is still transferred so it must be happening outside of the stream somehow.

Comment: You seem to be reading the input stream before that step. Of course it will block when you try to open it again.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry for that. I was re-creating some code from work and ended up copying from a different site than I had originally used. I have made updates now.

Comment: Well, as long as you are already editing it, please change it into a [mcve] so that we can try it on our own machines and see the problem with our own eyes.

Comment: Does this help? [How to use ProgressMonitorInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394714/how-to-use-progressmonitorinputstream)

Comment: @Abra No. Unfortunatly I needed to use a process not a file reader.

Comment: @RealSkeptic That is the minimal reproducible.